How can I fix corrupted android using an SD card?
I have a Samsung A34 which which I tried to root. I messed up somewhere and now I'm stuck in a continuous reboot cycle. Factory Reset button has no effect.  When I am able to finally get to the recovery screen, I do see I have the option to boot through the SD card, but every solution I tried on Google to download an image or software to the SD card was unable to be read by the phone. No computer will recognize the phone via USB cable either so my only option is some kind of recovery thru the SD card. If anyone knows how I can fix this, I would greatly appreciate the help. I will leave the screenshot that the phone always displays after I try to us the SD card to upload a fix. Thanks.


Samsung A34 is a Mediatek based phone. Such phone usually use special Mediatek (MTK) flash tools and they work when the phone is in switched off state. That screenshot looks like from a recovery ROM. If you try this way make sure to only use official full OTA images published by Samsung for your exact device model.

There's no "procedure via SD card". Commenting just in case the first comment wasn't sufficiently explicit.
